# in R leaflet, how can i increase the table width inside the pop up using htmltable?

Tags: r, html-table, leaflet

using the below code , i just need to increase the spacing between the two columns in the table

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlTable)

df <- read.csv(textConnection(
  "Name,Lat,Long
  Samurai Noodle,47.597131,-122.327298
  Kukai Ramen,47.6154,-122.327157
  Tsukushinbo,47.59987,-122.326726"
))

table <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b= c("a", "b", "c"))

leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = htmlTable(table, rnames = F))
```

the result is the below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be another solution

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)

df <- read.csv(textConnection(
  "Name,Lat,Long
  Samurai Noodle,47.597131,-122.327298
  Kukai Ramen,47.6154,-122.327157
  Tsukushinbo,47.59987,-122.326726"
))

table <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b= c("a", "b", "c"))

leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = popupTable(table, row.numbers = FALSE, feature.id = TRUE))
```